# Function returned undefined, expected Promise or value in Firebase cloud node function

Tags: node.js, firebase, amazon-ec2, cloud, google-cloud-functions

I am getting this error in my firebase functions log functions get deployed successfully.
The code producing the error is given below

```
exports.restartAWS_Instance = functions.database.ref('stats/instances/{aws_id}')
    .onUpdate((change, context) => {
    var aws_instance = context.params.aws_id;   
    var value = change.after.val();
    if(value == 1){
        if (aws_instance === "reset_aws_premium"){
            aws.config.update({
                accessKeyId: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX', 
                secretAccessKey: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX', 
                region: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
            });
            var ec2 = new aws.EC2();
            var params = {
              InstanceIds: [
                'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
              ]
            };
            console.log("Initiating server restart for aws_premium.");
            return ec2.stopInstances(params, function(err, data) {
                if (err) console.log(err, err.stack);
                else{
                    console.log("aws_premium stopped.");
                    var at = new Date();
                    var time = at.setSeconds(at.getSeconds()+Number(45));
                    return schedule.scheduleJob("aws_premium", new Date(time), function(){
                        return ec2.startInstances(params, function(err, data) {
                            if (err) {
                                return false;
                            }
                            else{
                                schedule.cancelJob("aws_premium");
                                console.log("aws_premium started again.");
                                return true;
                            }
                        });
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

And firebase log shows:

```
12:01:55.596 PM restartAWS_Instance Function returned undefined, expected Promise or value

12:01:54.126 PM restartAWS_Instance Function returned undefined, expected Promise or value

12:01:16.985 PM restartAWS_Instance aws_free started again.

12:00:26.185 PM restartAWS_Instance aws_free stopped.

12:00:15.689 PM restartAWS_Instance Error serializing return value: TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON

12:00:15.397 PM restartAWS_Instance Initiating server restart for aws_free
```

What i am doing wrong here? What return statement i am missing?

Answer (score 0):

Cloud Functions for Firebase triggered by events in the background **must return a promise** (or in certain cases a value, e.g. `return false;`).

I suggest you watch this set of videos from the Firebase team which explains this key aspect:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7IkUgCLr5oA&t=328s

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=652XeeKNHSk&t=308s

The first one is more about HTTP Functions that are triggered through an HTTP request (so not with a background event) while the second is focused on background event triggered Functions, but it is advised to watch the first one before watching the second one.

I also suggest you study some of the official samples that you will find here: https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples

So, more concretely, you should find a way for having the `ec2.stopInstances()` method returning a promise.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. Will check and update you soon.

Comment: @AkshayHiwale hello, did you have time to check this answer?